# Will Prism Nana be an actual anime?

Tags: prism-nana

Last I knew, all the PVs were for a Pachinko game. Will SHAFT actually turn it into an anime? If so, does anyone know when are they planning to release it?

Comment: have there been rumours, or are you just hoping it might be?

Comment: I know the voice cast was announced, but still there was ambiguity if that meant simply for the pachinko game or _something_ else. I'm looking for more conclusive evidence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is going to be an anime, though details are still rather sparse. If you go to [their website](http://www.prism-nana.com/index.php), under the About section, it says:

> 新アニメーション企画が遂に始動！

or, in English, "A new animation project is starting!". They would not describe the series that way if it were solely a Pachinko series. [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-04-26/studio-shaft-streams-prism-nana-anime-last-pilot-promo) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_Suite_Prism_Nana) both confirm that this will be some sort of anime.

At this point, that's essentially all we know. We don't know when it will be released (the "final PV" was 3 months ago, so it's probably nearing release, but there's still no date). We don't know what format it will be released in. They will be present at Comiket 84, so we're very likely to get more information in another week or so, but for now as far as I can tell they've made no definitive statements regarding release dates or format.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what's wrong with this answer?